# Android Virtual Device won't load

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm using Android Studio (not Eclipse), and the emulator won't load, it just shows a black screen.  I'm on a Max OS X Yosemite and I installed the Intel HAXM installer in the SDK downloads manager, but the screen is still black like before.  I'm not sure what to do next... 
Thanks for the help.

In response to codecats...thank you but I cannot understand Intel's instructions.  They say:

> "The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to finish installation"

Where is this "Extras Directory"?  Thanks.

Comment: There's a step by step that includes X.10 at https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks but..Where do you find the Extras Directory where I can run the installer?

Comment: Extras directory is when you use the Android SDK Manager (/users/AndroidSDK/HAXM/android_sdk-macrosx/extras/Intel x86 Em.......
. If you just install it off the web, you don't necessarily have to go that way..